# The net value of electric current

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, charge

If i have electron moved to the left And another electron moved to the right, will the net current be zero?
Because i read that in some cases such as those involving gases And electrolytes, the current is the result of Flow of both positive And negative charges.

Comment: Electrons have negative charges. The flow in the opposite direction to that of the positive charges, ususally ions of the electrolyte or gas.

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Ahmad Eldesokey!  In essence, I think you're correct but your question doesn't lend itself to a substantial answer thus this comment.  Note that a flow of positive charge 'to the right' is essentially equivalent to similar flow of negative charge 'to the left'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the situation of electrons moving left and right, the current would be zero. However, typically, we generate current by applying an electric field (through a potential difference), so it would be difficult to get your electrons to move in opposite directions in response to the electric field.

However, you could take a negative and positive charge, and they would move in opposite directions in response to the electric field. 
But, in this case, due to the opposite signs of the charges, they both contribute to current in the same direction (motion of negative charge in one direction contributes the same current as the motion of a positive charge in the opposite direction with the same velocity).

This is how both negative and positive ions can contribute to current (in response to an electric field) in the case of some electrolytes.